# Execute a function when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, onload

I have this function set up to execute when you click an element. I would like it to be executed when the page loads instead.

```
///// COLLAPSED/EXPAND LEFT MENU /////
    jQuery('.togglemenu').click(function(){
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('togglemenu_collapsed')) {

            //if(jQuery('.iconmenu').hasClass('vernav')) {
            if(jQuery('.vernav').length > 0) {
                if(jQuery('.vernav').hasClass('iconmenu')) {
                    jQuery('body').addClass('withmenucoll');
                    jQuery('.iconmenu').addClass('menucoll');
                } else {
                    jQuery('body').addClass('withmenucoll');
                    jQuery('.vernav').addClass('menucoll').find('ul').hide();
                }
            } else if(jQuery('.vernav2').length > 0) {
            //} else {
                jQuery('body').addClass('withmenucoll2');
                jQuery('.iconmenu').addClass('menucoll2');
            }

            jQuery(this).addClass('togglemenu_collapsed');

            jQuery('.iconmenu > ul > li > a').each(function(){
                var label = jQuery(this).text();
                jQuery('<li><span>'+label+'</span></li>')
                    .insertBefore(jQuery(this).parent().find('ul li:first-child'));
            });
        } else {

            //if(jQuery('.iconmenu').hasClass('vernav')) {
            if(jQuery('.vernav').length > 0) {
                if(jQuery('.vernav').hasClass('iconmenu')) {
                    jQuery('body').removeClass('withmenucoll');
                    jQuery('.iconmenu').removeClass('menucoll');
                } else {
                    jQuery('body').removeClass('withmenucoll');
                    jQuery('.vernav').removeClass('menucoll').find('ul').show();
                }
            } else if(jQuery('.vernav2').length > 0) {  
            //} else {
                jQuery('body').removeClass('withmenucoll2');
                jQuery('.iconmenu').removeClass('menucoll2');
            }
            jQuery(this).removeClass('togglemenu_collapsed');   

            jQuery('.iconmenu ul ul li:first-child').remove();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the click when page load by:

```
jQuery('.togglemenu').click(function() {
    // ...
}).click(); // add .click() here / also works with .trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this function into `$(document).ready()`'s callback, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add document.ready function before your JS code and one line code cha, like this

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 console.log( "ready!" );
 if(!jQuery('.togglemenu').hasClass('togglemenu_collapsed')) {
   ......
 });
```

See this [$( document ).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)   and try it !